# Why did the ullage motors for the S-IVB TLI burn shut down prior to S-IVB ignition?

Tags: saturn-v, ullage

I found "[Technical Information Summary AS-501: Apollo Saturn V Flight Vehicle](http://web.mit.edu/digitalapollo/Documents/Chapter5/saturnas501.pdf)" when looking for info about the Saturn V staging sequence. It contains a nice diagram on pages 14-16 showing the various events from liftoff to TLI, with approximate times after liftoff for each event. The ordering of events for the TLI burn caught my eye, though. Here are the events prior to the reignition of the S-IVB, with approximate time after liftoff:

- S-IVB Restart preparations ~11,235
- S-IVB Ullage engines on ~11,235
- S-IVB LH$_2$ and Lox vent valves close ~11,235
- S-IVB LH$_2$ and Lox chilldown pump off ~11,561
- **S-IVB Ullage engines off ~11,565**
- **2nd ignition S-IVB engine ~11,570**

Specifically, the ullage engines shut down prior to the S-IVB igniting. This seems strange to me, as I thought that the acceleration was needed to ensure the fuel was settled against the bottom of the tank. Cutting the ullage engines prior to ignition seems like it'd give the fuel an opportunity to drift away from the fuel inlets, potentially causing issues.

Why do the ullage motors cut out before S-IVB ignition? Is it an error in the diagram? If not, why did this not problematic for the Apollo missions?

Comment: It was only for 5 seconds.

Comment: @OrganicMarble So was the assumption that there just wasn't enough time for the fuel to drift away? I don't know what rate the fuel drifts away in cases like this

Comment: Looking at pg 40 it takes almost 5 seconds from the start command to when the J-2 reaches 90% thrust.  Maybe this is just a definition of terms thing.  Anyway, that's a nice document, thanks for posting.

Comment: If they start the fuel and oxidiser pumps before ignition that flow of cold mass should produce some thrust so that the fuel and oxidiser does not drift away from the pump inlets.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I guess that would depend on whether "2nd ignition S-IVB engine" corresponds to the 0 second mark on page 40. At least to me, it seems to imply that the ignition command is given 5 seconds after ullage shutdown, but as you said it may be a definition thing.

Comment: @lijat The timeline says that the chilldown pump turns off ~4 seconds prior to ullage motor shutdown, so I'm not sure how much thrust would be present from whatever is left.

Comment: @awksp if ignition should have any fuel to ignite some kind of mass flow from pumps or presure will probably have to occure. Are the chilldown pumps the same pumps providing fuel flow or is tha another pump system?

Comment: @lijat That is true, but at least according to the document propellant and oxidizer flow starts after the ignition command, so I'm not sure they're counting on pre-ignition flow for acceleration. Based on that, too, I don't think the chilldown pumps are the same as the main fuel/oxidizer pumps

Answer (score 6):

This [document](https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/saturn_apollo/documents/Third_Stage.pdf) states (sorry for image, I couldn't copy the text) that after the ullage engines cut off, the LH2 Continuous Propulsive Vent System kicks in and continues to settle the propellants.

[image]

[image]

(Diagram from [here](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap08fj/pdf/sa503-flightmanual.pdf) - emphasis mine)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about restart for TLI, which uses two (70 lb thrust each) ACS thrusters, since the solid APS ullage thrusters have already been used (and jettisoned).  See the answer to https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/why-did-the-s-iv-b-refer-to-jettisoning-its-ullage

Answer (score 2):

The S-IVB had ACS thrusters, one of which was used for ullage but not part of the "ullage thrusters" usually listed.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I'm a tad late to the party, but the ACS thrusters in question are the [Auxillary Propulsion System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-IVB#Auxiliary_Propulsion_System). You can find more detailed information in the [SA-503 flight manual](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap08fj/pdf/sa503-flightmanual.pdf), beginning on page 6-20.